# List of authors in git since a given commit

Tags: git

I want a way to list all git authors that

1. Is only since a given commit.
2. Is unique.

These two are easy, and I've seen some solutions to this online, most using `git log --format`.  But none that I saw fits the additional requirements:

1. Is ordered by commit date.  So if John Smith committed before Aaron Meurer, his name should appear before mine (I'm Aaron Meurer).
2. Respects .mailmap.  As far as I can tell, only `git shortlog` does this, and it gives a bunch of extra stuff that I don't want.   But maybe I'm wrong.  Or maybe those of you who are more handy with `sed` and friends than I am would just use that.

(by the way, how do I make Markdown *not* restart the numbering?)

I also want a way to order it by last name, but this is relatively easy.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following format specifiers will solve your second concern:

%aN: author name (respecting .mailmap)
%aE: author email (respecting .mailmap)
%cN: committer name (respecting .mailmap)
%cE: committer email (respecting .mailmap)

So discounting the duplicate author part, you want something like

```
git log <commit>.. --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse
```

I suspect you could pipe it through something that does a hash-table based deduplication, a perl oneliner would be trivial:

```
git log <commit>.. --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse | perl -e 'my %dedupe; while (<STDIN>) { print unless $dedupe{$_}++}'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually don't want the `<%aE>` part, but that's easy to remove, and good to know.

Comment: Unique authors in last 50 commits:
`git log HEAD~50.. --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse | sort | uniq`

Comment: @cxreg, why use a perl script when you can use `sort -u`. i.e.,
`git log <commit>.. --format="%aN <%aE>" --reverse | sort -u`. from http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4519/list-all-authors-of-a-particular-git-project

Comment: These solutions using sort do not preserve commit order, which is requirement #1, and is the reason I used the perl oneliner

Answer (score 38):

Note for people who want "global stat":

```
git shortlog -s -n -e
```

Give the global stats commits by author.

The options mean:

- `-s` / `--summary`: Suppress commit description and provide a commit count summary only.
- `-n` / `--numbered`: Sort output according to the number of commits per author instead of author alphabetic order.
- `-e` / `--email`: Show the email address of each author.