# How do I get the total number of authors contributed to a git repository by using the terminal?

Tags: git

I want to find out how many people contributed to a git repository. So basically I just want a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of authors in git since a given commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482436/list-of-authors-in-git-since-a-given-commit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+authors

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
git log --all --pretty="%an" | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: I am wondering why this doesn't correspond to the number of contributors I find on GitHub.

Comment: Probably because you are considering all branches and not just one branch? Also, maybe they use a different method for calculation? By email? A given developer might change email any time so might get a single name and multiple mails.

Answer (score 1):

Git has this build in withe the `shortlog` command

```
git shortlog -s -n --all
```

---

#### `git shortlog`

> **git-shortlog** - Summarize git log output
>
> **`-s, --summary`**
>   Suppress commit description and provide a commit count summary only.
>
> **`-n, --numbered`**
>   Sort output according to the number of commits per author instead of author alphabetic order.
>
> **`-all`**
>   Collect records form all branches

**Note:**
If you want to exclude merges add the `--no-merges` flag as well

[image]

To get a single count add the `| sort | uniq | wc -l` as @eftshift0 suggested

```
git shortlog -s -n --all --no-merges | sort | uniq | wc -l
```